# How to detect the exact flow between two methods in a huge project

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, hierarchy

Given:

- eclipse
- huge java project

Hope: finding an easy way to detect punctually the calling hierarchy/flow where from a method is called another method.

Pale solution - eclipse callee hierarchy - but you need to expand manually each level - and there are hundreds of nodes, not too efficient.

Can you please tell me if you know a shortcut for this?

Thank you, 
Roxana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a very nice solution but it should do the job.
If you have a *test version* of the project you can just throw a `Exception` in the second method and in the stack trace you should be able to see the flow starting from first method.

Comment: this is quite an ingenious approach, thank you:) but the problem is that you may have only the jar for the backend method, with source attached, it is harder to add the exception.

Comment: Yes indeed , i assumed you had all the sources

Comment: you can try another thing : `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();`  it should give you the stack trace of the current thread , http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()

Comment: If the JAR file has sources included (or downloadable), you can get the sources and re-create a project with them. Then you can add the Exception. Even if you can't find sources, you can use tools like *Java Decompiler* to extract the *pure* source of the class in question and use it to override the same class in the JAR file. (Note: *pure* because it doesn't have anything ignored by the original compiler, like comments)

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way is to use `eclipse` to debug the `huge project` by applying `Breakpoints` .

Comment: This would likely be even slower than using the call hierarchy, I believe the OP wants a quick way to see the full hierarchical tree without manually going down each node.